# mysqldump slow on Windows unless piped to file

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump, windows

Running mysqldump without piping to file such as:

```
mysqldump -u root -pPASS db
```

is really slow on windows. If I do

```
mysqldump -u root -pPASS db > db.sql
```

it runs fast.

This might not seem like a big deal as I can always pipe to a file. BUT I am using mysqldump from a script and I just want the raw output so I don't have to load the file in memory or save a temp file.

Linux and Mac there is NOT a difference if I pipe it to a file or just let it output.

Is there a way to fix this? This is for mysql 5.6.x

The full command I run is:

```
mysqldump --user=$db_username --password=$db_password --tz-utc=false --single-transaction --routines --triggers db
```

but I have tried a lot of combos and nothing makes it fast.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the bounty message `Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources.`, the only thing I could do is just mention that mysqldump is already buffering as little as possible. Why can I say that ???

By default, the option [--opt](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_opt) is enabled. The MySQL Documentation says this about [--opt](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_opt):

> This option, enabled by default, is shorthand for the combination of --add-drop-table --add-locks --create-options --disable-keys --extended-insert --lock-tables --quick --set-charset. It gives a fast dump operation and produces a dump file that can be reloaded into a MySQL server quickly.
>
> Because the --opt option is enabled by default, you only specify its converse, the --skip-opt to turn off several default settings. See the discussion of mysqldump option groups for information about selectively enabling or disabling a subset of the options affected by --opt.

Please note that [--quick](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_quick) is already enabled because [--opt](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_opt) is enabled.

What does [--quick](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_quick) do ???

> This option is useful for dumping large tables. It forces mysqldump to retrieve rows for a table from the server a row at a time rather than retrieving the entire row set and buffering it in memory before writing it out.

Since [--quick](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_quick) is already enabled, each row is being dumped directly to stdout without buffering. You may have to just [bite the bullet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bite_the_bullet) and disable [--quick](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_quick) by using `--skip-quick`. What that will do is buffer a whole table into RAM (which you didn't want to do in the first place) and then spill it out to stdout.

In your question, you said something interesting

> Linux and Mac there is NOT a difference if I pipe it to a file or just let it output.

Since you said that, you have reached a critical moment

[image: kxm]

I can say that mysqldump is not really the problem. The problem is the OS and/or hardware.

Evidently, the computer you are using for Windows is not performant for screen I/O.

Since MacOS runs like Linux, I would tend to blame Windows OS. My guess is that even with a far better computer (faster CPU, more RAM), mysqldump may still not perform better if Windows cannot buffer screen I/O effectively.

Your fix for this would be to tune Windows. [Godspeed, Spiderman !!!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AglV2jLZ4qU)

Comment: The problem has something to do with php/apache. On php 5.3.8 and php 7.3 mysqldump using the same methods works very fast. Any other places to look? I am serving the mysqldump through passthru function in php